# Facebook chat button of my website in android webview is not opening the messenger app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, facebook-messenger

I have a website which is integrated with facebook chat option. I made a webview of my website and can see that chat button in my android app but the problem is **on clicking on the chat button it is not redirecting me to messenger app installed in my phone instead it is redirecting me to a page written 1 on it.**

on the other hand while opening my website in chrome on my mobile(in mobile view mode) the chat functionality is working fine.

here is my MainActivity.java class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://geekyvisuals.github.io/website/");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack())
        webView.goBack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("https://geekyvisuals.github.io/website")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

What should i do to open messenger from my android app directly?

Comment: were you able to fix it ?

Comment: @KaranSethi check my solution.

Answer (score 1):

For "intent:" open your messenger URL with an external browser.

Detailed solution is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65344827/4850004).

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("www.messenger.com") {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: still not opening @Steven

Answer (score 0):

**try this way  (as of 2021/10/27):**

```
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    
     ........

    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                    if (url.startsWith("http"))
                        return false //open web links as usual
    
                    if (url.startsWith("intent:")) {
                        val intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)
                        val data = intent.data
                        data?.let {
                            try {
                                val scheme = data.scheme
                                if (FACEBOOK_APP_SCHEMA == scheme) {
                                    startActivity(intent)
                                    return true
                                }
                            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                                val marketIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(
                                    Uri.parse("$PLAY_STORE_URL${intent.getPackage()}")
                                )
                                if (marketIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                                    this@WebViewActivity.startActivity(marketIntent)
                                    return true
                                }
                            }
                        }
    
                    }
                    return false
                }
    
    
    }
    
........

        companion object {
            private const val FACEBOOK_APP_SCHEMA = "fb-messenger"
            private const val PLAY_STORE_URL = "market://details?id="
        }
```