# My Webview App keeps crashing for messenger chat

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-webview

Everything works as it should except messenger.
Code

```
if (url.startsWith("www.messenger.com")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
```

For messenger even for this general intent code it doesnt show the option to open with messenger

```
if (url.startsWith("intent")){
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(sendIntent);
                }
                return true;
            }
```

With protocol Error logs:

```
2020-08-28 17:21:24.098 16802-16802/com.mesports.ga E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mesports.ga, PID: 16802
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=intent://user/102700191461284/?intent_trigger=mme&ref=c4254e87a85bef8dd4c3e74bc771d099dda9c6bb22e340c644&nav=discover&source=customer_chat_plugin&source_id=1507329&metadata={"referer_uri":"https:\/\/m-esports.ga\/f2d7b535e73be5c"} }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2014)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1675)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4905)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4873)
        at com.mesports.ga.MainActivity$MyWebviewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(MainActivity.java:194)
        at android.webkit.WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebViewClient.java:77)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-418308173:16)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

even by using http and https protocols it is showing the same error

Here's the android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mesports.ga">
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `if (url.startsWith("www.messenger.com")` Urls for action view for browsers should start with a protocol. So use `if (url.startsWith("http://www.messenger.com")` or `if (url.startsWith("https://www.messenger.com")`. And let your url start with it! ;-).

Comment: Still the same @blackapps i have added the error logs for the protocol version too

Comment: its showing ` No Activity found to handle intent` but it loads when opened through chrome app

Comment: You have code for two intents. The second one looks not ok. But about which one are you talking? With the first one you try to open a browser. What you want with the second one is unknown. And it is also unclear what this has to do with a webview.

Comment: I want to open the chat in messenger app this is the website - www.m-esports.ga @blackapps

Comment: In second one I was just checking which options appear for the intent it showed all options but it didnt show messenger

Comment: @blackapps I have checked the other posts too and all of them have answers that aren't marked as answer by the people who have asked the question. It's still unresolved I guess.

Comment: Is there no way to do it then?

Comment: @Clare Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I tried and was able to extract the package from the URL of the intent, and then launch the activity using that package. Messenger App was launched but not as expected in the case of the chatbot. Did anyone made any progress on this or was able to find any solution or workaround? @blackapps

Comment: `if (url.startsWith("www.messenger.com")` That can never work. Didnt you mean `if (url.startsWith("https://www.messenger.com")` ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how to do it with WebView.

First, get Your Messenger URL from Page Settings-> Messaging. As shown in the below image.

[image]

After that handle the "intent:" case to be opened by an external browser. Use "https://" with your messenger URL.

```
if(url.startsWith("intent:"))
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://m.me/***********"));
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
```

And, you are done. Phew!

Comment: this would impose for all intents. I am using other intents too.

Comment: You can add some more text in url.startsWith("intent:") for messenger.
Example: url.startsWith("intent: //user/")

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your activity in manifest file

Comment: `<intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>`
This is the intent filter

Comment: Your intent filter has nothing to do with action view.

Comment: Can you answer how @FarukhTariq I have registered the main activity and the whole code is in it. Is something else required too?

Comment: @Clare your intent filters are correct in manifest but you need to declare your activity in manifest as well from your above code i am unable to find your activity inside your code.

Comment: @FarukhTariq I have added the manifest file too in the question do I need to add something else in manifest too?