# Facebook Customer Chat Plugin inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, content-security-policy

Is it possible to make Customer Chat Plugin works inside an iframe ?

It's adding `content-security-policy: frame-ancestors IFRAME_DOMAIN` and show `Refused to frame 'https://www.facebook.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors IFRAME_DOMAIN`

Comment: It might(!) work if you added both domains (the one hosting the iframe, and the one embedding it) to your whitelisted domains.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, FB Chat Plugin is intended to be embedded.

You have just to [whitelist](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin/#--------------------------------------) domains where Chat allowed to operate. This should fix `frame-ancestors` issue in the Facebook's CSP.

And maybe you'll [have to add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66256602/facebook-chat-plugin-issues-with-csp-frame-src-directive) `intent:` and `fb-messenger:` schemes.